# SS2.0 Display Message on Record

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'd like to use SS2.0 and the 'new' N/ui/message module to display warnings or errors when a user views a record.  In reality, I'd like to understand how to run any 2.0 client script code on record view.

I managed an example I can run, which works from the console:

```
require(['N/currentRecord', 'N/ui/message'],
    function(curr, mess) {
        var rec = curr.get();
        var status = rec.getValue('status');
        if (status === 'Unapproved Payment') {
            var myMsg = mess.create({
                title: "PAYMENT ERROR",
                message: status,
                type: mess.Type.ERROR
            }).show({
                duration: 500000
            });
        }});
```

Runs fine in edit mode(pageInit or wherever) but haven't found a method to load and execute on 'View'.  Is this even possible in 2.0? Do I have to use the 1.0 tricks still?

Comment: I think you need a SS2 before load on the view event. The new call is:

`form.clientScriptModulePath = './clientScriptPath.js'; ` The NS example lists the path as SuiteScripts/clientScriptPath.js but I hope the form I suggested works. Otherwise bundled or packaged (all in their own folder) will be hosed.

Comment: I could not get any of this code to execute appropriately using the clientScriptModule/FileId.  totally possible it was user error though.  i ended up wrapping the above example in a jquery event trigger, inside <script> tags, inside an inline html element that i add to a form in a beforeLoad UE.  it's nearly impossible to read, is fragile and messy, but it works for now. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the release 2018.2 they added a new method in `N/ui/serverWidget` module named `Form.addPageInitMessage(options)` and does exactly what OP wanted to do.

Given the example above it should look something like this.

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.0
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
*/
define(['N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/record'],
    function(serverWidget, record) {
        function beforeLoad(context) {

          var rec = context.newRecord;
          var status = rec.getValue('status');
          if (status === 'Unapproved Payment') {
           var myMsg = mess.create({
                title: "PAYMENT ERROR",
                message: status,
                type: mess.Type.ERROR,
                duration: 500000
           });
           context.form.addPageInitMessage({message: myMsg});
        }

    return {
        beforeLoad: beforeLoad 
    };
});
```

Comment: But this is assuming that you know you want to display the message on pageInit. What if you want to display the message after a btn is pressed? For example after a custom print btn is clicked display a reminder message.

I can imagine using some type of checkbox hack and refreshing the page but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 2):

so a working example. This is not good (not very portable and certainly not bundle friendly) but it works:

Server Side:

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(['N/record', 'N/log', 'N/ui/serverWidget'],
    function(record, log, ui) {
        function beforeLoad(context) {
            log.debug({title:'before load with '+ context.type +' on '+ context.form.title});
            if (context.type != 'view') return;
            log.debug({title:'setting client script'});

            var inline = context.form.addField({
                id:'custpage_trigger_it',
                label:'not shown',
                type: ui.FieldType.INLINEHTML,
            });
            inline.defaultValue = "jQuery(function($){ require(['/SuiteScripts/testSS2/testSimpleClient'], function(mod){ console.log('loaded'); mod.showMessage();});});</script>";



            //context.form.clientScriptModulePath = './testSimpleClient.js';
        }


    return {
        beforeLoad: beforeLoad 
    };
});
```

Client Side:

```
define(['N/ui/message', 'N/currentRecord'], function(msg, currentRecord){
    window.console.log('processing script');
    function showMessage() {
        var rec = currentRecord.get();
        window.console.log('record status is '+ rec.getValue('status'));
        if('Pending Approval' == rec.getValue('status')){
            var myMsg = msg.create({
                title: "Not Committed",
                message: rec.getValue('status'), //'Please Approve',
                type: msg.Type.ERROR
            }).show({
                duration: 10000
            });
        }
    }



    return {
        showMessage:showMessage
    };
});
```

Comment: agreed this isn't ideal, but it's essentially the same solution i ended up going with.  (Unsurprisingly, your's is clearer still than mine.) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW the following works in edit mode but not view mode. (See my other answer for a hack that works as of October 2016) I suspect this'll be fixed somewhere along the way since similar code has worked for years in SS1.0. If you have a business case please file a support case with Netsuite.

user event script:

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(['N/record', 'N/log'],
    function(record, log) {
        function beforeLoad(context) {
            log.debug({title:'before load with '+ context.type +' on '+ context.form.title});
            //if (context.type != 'view') return;
            log.debug({title:'setting client script'});
            context.form.clientScriptModulePath = './testSimpleClient.js'; //relative to the user event script file
        }

    return {
        beforeLoad: beforeLoad 
    };
});
```

with testSimpleClient being:

```
define(['N/ui/message', 'N/currentRecord'], function(msg, currentRecord){
    window.console.log('processing script');
    function showMessage(rec) {
        window.console.log('record status is '+ rec.getValue('status'));
        //if('Pending Approval' == rec.getValue('status')){
            var myMsg = msg.create({
                title: "PAYMENT ERROR",
                message: rec.getValue('status'), //'Please Approve',
                type: msg.Type.ERROR
            }).show({
                duration: 100000
            });
        //}
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
        showMessage(currentRecord.get());
    }, 1500);


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on help topic:

```
A current record instance can be accessed via the following ways:
 - The context object that gets passed into the client script entry point.
```

In view mode, you can only attach a user event script (beforeLoad).

N/currentRecord module only runs on client-side scripts which is why it didn't work.

Use N/record module instead.

Comment: actually the code with N/currentRecord works fine client side. See the working example

Comment: Yes. Basically, use *N/currentRecord* for client and *N/record* for server-side.