# Suitescript2 alert on ini

Tags: netsuite

Is it possible that suitescript 2 is not enable ?
I have the most simple script, that show an alert but it doesn't popup

Possible ?

Thanks

P.s. i'm willing to pay for thid

Comment: Are you trying to do something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40245943/ss2-0-display-message-on-record/40293127#40293127

Comment: Make sure that the script is indeed deployed to this record type.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you enabled SuiteScript options in  **Check Setup > Company > Setup Tasks > Enable Features > SuiteCloud.**

Make sure you deployed your script accordingly . Make sure there are no error in script execution log.

To make sure suitescript is working fine in Netsuite , you can write a simple suitelet and test it in script debugger. ( **Customization > Scripting > Script Debugger**).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see would be if you do not have SuiteScript enabled on your instance.  Check Setup > Company > Setup Tasks > Enable Features > SuiteCloud, and ensure that the SuiteScript options are enabled.

Aside from that, post some of your code, and/or any errors that you are seeing in the script execution log or the page that you are running the code on.

Comment: Finally I found the problem but I don't have a solution yet. I called netsuite and they said it's a known defect but I don't think so. I'm sure we are not the first one in the history.

We need to add a script to the customer record.

We found out that SalesForce added an Users Event Script. 
I'm writing a Client Script, thus the conclusion from Netsuite is that you can't have a User Even Scrip and a Client Script, thus the reason it's not working.

Again I still CAN'T believe it

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I can assure you that NetSuite has absolutely no limitation on the scripts that can be attached to records.  I have records with multiple user event scripts, client scripts, and even workflows.  Some of these have over twenty of each script due to so many random things that everyone needs.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem but I don't have a solution yet. I called netsuite and they said it's a known defect but I don't think so. I'm sure we are not the first one in the history.

We need to add a script to the customer record.

We found out that SalesForce added an Users Event Script. 
I'm writing a Client Script, thus the conclusion from Netsuite is that you can't have a User Even Scrip and a Client Script, thus the reason it's not working.

Again I still CAN'T believe it

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You certainly can have user event scripts and client scripts. You can have multiple of each type on a record.

Answer (score 0):

I "think" I found the problem. The event script is written in SS1 and what I'm doing is SS2.

I have moved my code back to SS1 and it's working.

I know it makes no sense but it's working

Comment: SS2 is not backward compatible with SS1,period.
You either write the script in SS1 or SS2.
You cannot mix both them up and expect them to work

Comment: Of course. I wrote "hello world" in SS2, tried it with a customer and it's working fine. I take the same script with another customer and it doesn't fire.