# Show NetSuite Inactive Customers Differently?

Tags: netsuite

In NetSuite, is there some way to show inactive customers differently to active ones? We have a single checkbox which indicates when a customer is inactive, and it's very easy to miss. I'd like something to change if it's checked - the color of the form or some text or something - anything that's a bit more visible than a single checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a user event script that shows a message when the customer record is loaded. The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40245943/ss2-0-display-message-on-record) has a sample user event script. You will probably want to use message.Type.WARNING or message.Type.INFORMATION for your need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the message module.
When even any person opening a customer record you need to get the value of inactive in before load user evet if the inactive is true then you can show an alert with green color using the below code. the form you can get from the before load context.

```
define(['N/ui/message'],
function(message){
 var myMsg = message.create({
             message: "This customer is INACTIVE",
             type: message.Type.INFORMATION,
             duration: 0,
           });
form.addPageInitMessage({
       message: myMsg,
      });
});
```